# How to empty out an arrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sample code as such :

```
async function example() {
  const blob = new Blob(['bobbyhadz.com']);
  const buf = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  console.log(buf.byteLength);
}

example();
```

However `buf` remains in memory and occupies the ram to a great extent ( as much as the blob itself I suppose ). How can I empty it out so I can get the memory back?

Comment: Once all references are released, it will be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: How are you determining that the memory is being held specifically because of the array buffer? It may be, for example, that the engine is just holding onto otherwise unused memory on the off chance that something else will need it.

Comment: @Ouroborus I am using node --inspect and I can see that buffer is not being garbage collected by node.

Comment: @Brad for some unknown reasons, gc doesn't work. Is there anyway I can do it manually?

Comment: `node --inspect` does not explain how you concluding that the data is not GCed.  We need to know exactly how you have concluded it was not GCed.  For example, it may be GCed, but not returned to the OS and marked as free memory in the node heap to be used by future allocations.  Also, Buffers come out of different memory than regular JS variables so it has to be tracked separately.

Comment: Have you tried `buf = new ArrayBuffer(0);`?

Comment: Note that there's no where in the code you show that you're waiting for `example()` to actually finish and resolve its promise before measuring memory usage.  You would also have to make sure you were measuring after GC did its thing (which is of unknown timing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a garbage collection problem that only occurs on Ubuntu. I tackled it by manually cleaning it up as such :

```
const startCleaning = ()=> {
   const cleanUpTimer = setInterval(()=>{
  if(global.gc){
  const checkIt = ~~(process.memoryUsage().arrayBuffers / 1024)
  console.log('INTERVAL ACTIVE' , checkIt)
if(checkIt > 5000){
  console.log('CLEANED!' , checkIt)
  global.gc()  
}else{
    console.log('INTERVAL DEACTIVATED!' , checkIt )
    clearInterval(cleanUpTimer)
} 
}
},5000)}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.use let instead off const

```
async function example() {
  let blob = new Blob(['bobbyhadz.com']);
  let buf = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    buf = [];
  console.log(buf.byteLength);
}

example();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).